# How to assess if a hypothesis makes sense?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

Assume that you are comparing different keyboard layouts (QWERTY, Colemak, Dvorak) for their typing speed. You are also interested in exploring whether the user's gender (male, female) has an effect on the typing speed.

In this case, does it make sense to compare (I know that it is possible to do a statistical test) certain questions e.g., male users who use QWERTY against female users who use Colemak?

Also, on a related note, are there any algorithms/specifications that help us differentiate hypothesis/research questions that make sense to compare from those that don't?

Comment: "Make sense" seems to be an issue of logic or of the field of study, but in any event it doesn't seem to be very well defined. Could you edit this post to provide a little more detail concerning what you mean by this phrase and its connection with statistics?

Comment: It is an issue of logic. My question is not whether we can do statistical analysis for such questions, but rather, would it make sense to perform statistical analysis to show that there is a significant difference. Based on the above example, we can use statistical analysis to show male users who use QWERTY are significantly better than female users who use Colemak - but, IMHO, it seems like a comparison between apples and oranges. But, I can't seem to find any literature to base my reasoning upon!

Comment: It seems to me that no matter how you group people and layouts, you are still talking about comparing typing speeds. I do not see how an "apples and oranges" metaphor applies.